# Get frame rate of a video in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, html5-video

How can I obtain the frame rate of a video or the current frame using a HTML5 video player?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need a serverside script for this, there is limited support for metadata in the `<video>` object - and most are browserspecific.

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
var q = "?file=http://mediafiles.tld/playme.avi";
xhr.open("GET", "/path/to/identify.php" + q, true);
xhr.send();
var videodata = eval("("+xhr.responseText+")");
```

And then on the serverside create a player that fires like, first frame here - and does not show anything nor plays audio. The functionality below will simply start up the associated codec and retreive informations by '-identify'. By use of mplayer, the server must ofc have this present and be able to decode the movie/audio to provide valid data.

```
<?php

ob_start();
system('mplayer -identify -frames 1 -vo null -ao null '.$_GET['file'].' 2>/dev/null|egrep "[A-Z_]+="');
$out = ob_get_clean();
$data = array();
foreach(explode("\n", $out) as $line) {
    list($k, $v) = explode("=", trim($line));
    $data[trim($k)] = trim($v);
}
header("Content-Type: application/x-json");
header("E-Tag: " . substr(0,16,md5($_GET['file']));
print json_encode($data);

?>
```